# Trigger script across multiple Google accounts? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I know I can use Google Apps Script to send an email from the account that is currently logged in. I'm wondering, is it possible for a "master" Script on one account to push a trigger of some kind out to a series of other Google Accounts, telling them to run their scripts?

Essentially I need to send a bunch of emails from various different accounts, and the user who runs the script won't be able to log into all of them. I'm looking for a way to make all these accounts listen for a central signal to run their scripts.

Does this make sense? Any thoughts?

Thank you,
Pacific 231

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes...

You will have to write one script for each account that will run as a service (deployed as webApp with its own url) and your master script will have to call each of them using an urlFetch with some parameters added to the url telling them what email to send. You'll have to add some security feature to these calls.
Every webApp service will run as the user who wrote the script and will be accessible to anyone (if in a Google Apps account you will be able to restrict the use to members of the Google Apps community).

This is not too hard to do but will require some work though...

We'll be glad to help you if you meet specific issues.